# No wifi adapter found Ubuntu 20.04 Asus

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Every single tutorial I found after hours of trying has not worked for me at all. I have a Asus G15 Zephyrus gaming laptop. Secure boot and fast boot both disabled. If somebody could diagnose the issue from my outputs and tell me how to fix it I'd appreciate it.

Outputs:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 30 Mar 2022 01:28 EDT -0400

Booted last: 30 Mar 2022 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.13.0-37-generic #42~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 15 15:44:28 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8162] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:208f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7961]
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:4680]
    Kernel modules: mt7921e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:521d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3563 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b05:19b6 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. N-KEY Device
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c547 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1028096  3 mt76,mt7921e,mt76_connac_lib
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              888832  4 mt76,mt7921e,mac80211,mt76_connac_lib
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
asus_wmi               36864  3 asus_nb_wmi,hid_asus,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  5 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.20.10.2/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
       valid_lft 85890sec preferred_lft 85890sec
    inet6 2600:100e:bf1c:174f:896d:b322:5d5d:5428/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604294sec preferred_lft 85561sec
    inet6 2600:100e:bf1c:174f:2ec:5974:46a5:af95/64 scope global mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d5e:c850:4ea4:ac11/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 172.20.10.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> scope link metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.2 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         839       1  0 01:19 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Apple, Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        iPhone5/5C/5S/6
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ipheth
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.13.0-37-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:06:00.3/usb1/1-2/1-2:4.2/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       2a5d6536-ce5e-3b1f-916f-7567816efd5b
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.20.10.2/28
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.20.10.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.20.10.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 172.20.10.0/28, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1648693361
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        ip_address = 172.20.10.2
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        next_server = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       routers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.240
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         2600:100e:bf1c:174f:896d:b322:5d5d:5428/64
IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         2600:100e:bf1c:174f:2ec:5974:46a5:af95/64
IP6.ADDRESS[3]:                         fe80::d5e:c850:4ea4:ac11/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            fe80::940c:98ff:fe20:e664
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 2600:100e:bf1c:174f::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::940c:98ff:fe20:e664, mt = 20100
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.DNS[1]:                             fe80::940c:98ff:fe20:e664
DHCP6.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp6_name_servers = fe80::940c:98ff:fe20:e664
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/3
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   2a5d6536-ce5e-3b1f-916f-7567816efd5b | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.13.0-37-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp3s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.1/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/5G Cabana Beach.nmconnection]] (600 root)
[connection] id=5G Cabana Beach | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=5G Cabana Beach
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp3s0    no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp3s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.13.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.13.0-37-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.13.0-37-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/dkms.conf]
blacklist rtw88_8821ce

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libopenni-sensor-pointclouds0.conf]
blacklist gspca_kinect

[/etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf]
alias pci:v000014C3d00000608sv*sd*bc*sc*i* mt7921e

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

`sudo dmesg | grep mt7`
NOTE: there were about 5 more [ ###.######] outputs in the middle of the section, but I reached the character limit for a post so I deleted them from the output, they were identical to the other middle ones with a different [ ] number.

```
[  124.059327] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  124.061367] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  124.063318] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  130.302903] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  130.304853] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  130.306797] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  130.308830] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  212.116227] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  212.120018] Modules linked in: bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus usbhid hid_generic mfd_aaeon
[  227.119811] Modules linked in: hid_apple apple_mfi_fastcharge bnep intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm_amd nls_iso8859_1 amdgpu snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel kvm snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep mt7921e mt76_connac_lib btusb btrtl crct10dif_pclmul btbcm snd_pcm mt76 btintel nouveau ghash_clmulni_intel mac80211 bluetooth aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd iommu_v2 cryptd snd_seq_midi_event gpu_sched mxm_wmi ecdh_generic drm_ttm_helper rapl ecc joydev input_leds asus_nb_wmi wmi_bmof hid_multitouch efi_pstore snd_rawmidi ttm snd_seq cfg80211 drm_kms_helper snd_seq_device cec snd_timer rc_core snd_rn_pci_acp3x i2c_algo_bit snd_pci_acp3x fb_sys_fops libarc4 snd syscopyarea sysfillrect ccp sysimgblt soundcore ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi typec mac_hid amd_pmc asus_wireless sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_asus
```

Comment: This particular device seems to need a 5.13 kernel or newer to function. Could you [edit] your question to include the terminal output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @matigo I reformatted my outputs for a script suggested - it does appear it is using a 5.13 kernel

Comment: @waltinator no, I edited my outputs to that script because it's informative but my question is if someone could look at my outputs and tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep mt7`

Comment: @chili555 edited it

Comment: is it a new computer? have you ever seen working wifi on it?

Comment: @Andra wifi has always worked on Windows, Ubuntu wifi comes and goes (almost always goes)